# Error importing Virtual Machine as applience in Virtual Box

Tags: import, export, virtual-machine, virtualbox

The host is a Windows 8.1 OS and the version of Virtual Box is 5.1.
The error is:

```
Error reading OVA 'E:\Xubuntu.ova' (VERR_TAR_UNEXPECTED_EOS).


Codice 'uscita: 
VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
Componente: 
ApplianceWrap
Interfaccia: 
IAppliance {8398f026-4add-4474-5bc3-2f9f2140b23e}
```

Any idea on what is going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

> **It is enough to upgrade Virtual Box.**

In my case from 5.1 to 5.2.6. Everything works fine!